# jquery addClass method stops working when called from a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, addclass

Im trying to override a class of the bellow label :

```
<label id='wishlist' class="btn btn-default btn-custom-small ">                                                                  
    <input type="checkbox" class="searchfilter collapse" value="my_wishlist" name="my_wishlist" data-toggle="button"> My Wishlist                                             </label>
```

I can do it with the bellow code snipets

```
 $('#wishlist').removeClass('btn-custom-small').addClass('btn-custom-small active');
```

But the code stops working as soon as it is called in a click event:

```
$("#wishlist").click(function() {
                $('#wishlist').removeClass('btn-custom-small').addClass('btn-custom-small active');
            });
```

Comment: why are you removing and adding the same class? So is the element on the page when you add the click? `console.log($("#wishlist").length);`

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/czsa6akt/  Do you have code that actually demonstrates the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted out the issue by moving the code to ajax success handler.

```
success: function(data){
if( filters == 'my_wishlist' )  $('#wishlist').removeClass('btn-custom-small').addClass('btn-custom-small active');
```